# Structure of lists in foreach package

Tags: r, list, foreach

I have found a feature/bug in the foreach package, which I do not understand. Perhaps someone can explain me this behaviour:

I created a for-loop with the `foreach` package (I use them together with mutlicore calculations, but here just in a sequentiell example, the bug appears in both variants). This loop runs `r` times. In every run a list with `c` entries is returned. So I expect a list with `r` entries, and every entry consists of `c` lists.

My code was the following one:

```
library(foreach)

clusters <- 10
runs <- 100

temp <- foreach(r = 1:runs,
                .combine = 'list',
                .multicombine = TRUE) %do% {

              signal_all <- lapply(1:clusters, function(x){

                return(1)

              })

              return(signal_all)
            } ## end do
```

With this code, all works as expected, see the following picture:

[image]

But when increasing `runs <- 101`, the output `temp` is this:

[image]

The expected list structure is destroyed. But when commenting out the line `.combine = 'list'` all works as expected.

```
library(foreach)

clusters <- 10
runs <- 100

temp <- foreach(r = 1:runs,
                .multicombine = TRUE) %do% {

              signal_all <- lapply(1:clusters, function(x){

                return(1)

              })

              return(signal_all)
            } ## end do
```

[image]

Can someone explain this behaviour? 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meanwhile I have found a solution.

The foreach function knows that some comine-functions (e.g. `c` or `cbind`) take many arguments, and will call them with up to 100 arguments (by default) in order to improve performance. With the argument `.maxcombine` you can set them manually.

```
library(foreach)

clusters <- 10
runs <- 101

temp <- foreach(r = 1:runs,
                .combine = 'list',
                .maxcombine = runs,
                .multicombine = T) %do% {

              signal_all <- lapply(1:clusters, function(x){

                return(1)

              })

              return(signal_all)
            } ## end do
```